# distribution of random variable nad expectation value

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

We throw a die as many times as we thrown $k$ tails and $k$ heads (it can't be one after another). Let $X$ be a number of throwing.
Set the distribution of $X$ and $\mathbb{E}X$

So, I've started from setting the set value of $X$ it is: $\left\{2k, 2k+1, 2k+2, \ldots , \infty \right\}$

Next $\mathbb{P}(X=2k)=\frac{ {2k \choose k} }{2^{2k}}$. And I've noticed it would be hard to set the rest of probablilities. Thats why I think to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X>x)=$ but I've stacked in it. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Note that $X=n$ with $n\geqslant2k$ when the $n-1$ first throws result in exactly $k-1$ tails and $n-k$ heads and the $n$th throw is tails, or when the same happens exchanging heads and tails. Thus, $$P(X=n)=2\cdot{n-1\choose k-1}\cdot\frac1{2^{n-1}}\cdot\frac12={n-1\choose k-1}\cdot\frac1{2^{n-1}}$$ and $$E(X)=\sum_{n\geqslant2k}n\cdot P(X=n)=\sum_{n\geqslant2k}2k\cdot{n\choose k}\cdot\frac1{2^n}=\cdots$$

Comment: (Traditional *die* have no heads and tails. For experiments with two results, one usually mentions *coins*.)